# Camera doesn't work for android 7.0

Tags: android

***I'm getting: android.os.FileUriExposedException.***

> When targeting Android N, file:// URIs are not allowed anymore. I know
>   We should use content:// URIs instead. However, my app needs file for
>   both image and video. Any ideas?

```
  mMediaUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(AppHelper.getDirectoryPath(),AppHelper.getFileName() + ".jpeg"));

  Intent iCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  iCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mMediaUri);
  startActivityForResult(iCamera, Constants.INTENT_CALL.CAPTURE_IMAGE);
```

**and onActivityResult**

```
case Constants.INTENT_CALL.CAPTURE_IMAGE:
String filePath=SiliCompressor.with(getActivity()).compress(mMediaUri.toString(), true);
```

> Please add sample code...if Available.

Comment: have you requested the permission for using camera at runtime?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Media/VideoRecordIntent

Comment: yes I have added the run time permission.... only targeting Android N gives android.os.FileUriExposedException....

Comment: Yes you should use a FileProvider. You are number #### who encounters this problem. Code has been published many times here. Your app needs a file? But the Camera app you use is happy with a content scheme.

Comment: @greenapps here I am getting error:String filePath=SiliCompressor.with(getActivity()).compress(mMediaUri.toString(), true);  do you know how to resolve it.

Comment: O are you getting an error? And you are not telling what error exactly? What do you have in mind? And why not post complete onActivityResult code?

Comment: @greenapps i got solution and error occurred because of sillicompressor as its take input as file not content...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research finally got relevant answer to my question just set min target sdk version to 23.